# Is there a difference between VBA.Left() and Left()?

Tags: excel, vba

I was informed, quite a while back, that a compatibility issue between older and newer versions of Excel was because of reference errors solved by prefixing VBA. to the core library functions. Left is just an example, any of the built in functions can be prefixed this way.

While I followed this advice in new projects our issue eventually turned out to be related to a complicated interaction between versions of Excel and registry values which were set by an install of Lync communicator. Revisiting the old issue I can't find any information regarding the use of VBA.[syntax] in VBA code. Does it do anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the Visual Basic Editor and open the Object Explorer with F2 or from the **View** menu you can see the libraries available in the upper dropdown list.

Prefixing the VBA library functions with `VBA.` ensures that Excel will not use a function with the same name from another library (so yes, it does something).

Having said this, it's very bad practice for a third-party library to replace a core VBA function, so I wouldn't recommmend using VBA. everywhere, it makes the code less readable.

Comment: Ah lovely. Obvious in retrospect. Egg of Columbus.